# Java: how to validate natural language text

Tags: java, nlp

I'm using OCR to recognize (German) text in an image. It works well but not perfectly. Sometimes a word gets messed-up. Therefore, I want to implement some sort of validation. Of course, I can just use a word list and find words that are similar to the messed-up word, but is there a way to check if the sentence is plausible with these words?

After all, my smartphone can give me good suggestions on how to complete a sentence.

Comment: Look for markov chains which is which element is more likely to appear after given element. You could do it at letter level (which letter is more likely) or at a word level (which is more involved). Letter level is most likely enough in your case. See here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Markov_chain_text_generator#Java

Comment: Sorry but without any code this question is way too broad to be answered here. Everyone will want to give his/her opinion. FYI: your smartphone can give you suggestions based on lists of words, sentences and how often the words are used. And if it is an online service from google.. then I am afraid it is too complicated to reproduce.

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program.

Comment: *After all, my smartphone can give me good suggestions on how to complete a sentence.* After all, Mike Tyson could still knock out you and me, and everybody else around here. Even though he is much older than you and me.

Comment: I still have a suggestion: You could download [a dictionary for auto correction](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries), and try to integrate it in your program. So that after running the OCR, you reiterate through your text and verify the words by comparing them with your dictionary. This won't work perfectly but at least it is feasible and gives you some chance to correct at least some words.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for Natural Language Processing (NLP) solutions. With them, you can validate syntactically the lexical (either the whole text, which may be better as some of them may take on consideration the context, or phrase by phrase).

I am not an expert in the area, but [this](https://analyticsindiamag.com/7-top-nlp-libraries-java-developers-should-know-in-2019/) article can help you to choose a tool to start trying.

Also, please notice: your keyboard on your cellphone is developed and maintained by specialized teams, either on Apple, Google or any other company that you use their app. So, please, don't underestimate this task: there are dozens of research areas on this, that includes either software engineers and linguistics specialists to achieve proper results.

Edit: well, two days later, I've just came to this link: https://medium.com/quick-code/12-best-natural-language-processing-courses-2019-updated-2a6c28aebd48